# Left join returning count of 1 even though no rows exist for that count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that looks like the following. It uses a `cte`:

```
SELECT  d.hour, 
        hourkey, 
        range, 
        COUNT(*) as 'count'
FROM dimhour d 
    LEFT JOIN cte2 
        ON d.hour = cte2.hourkey
        AND range IS NOT NULL
WHERE d.hour <= 23
GROUP BY d.hour, 
         hourkey, 
         range                
ORDER BY d.hour DESC
```

This is the result of this query:

```
hour   hourkey  range    count
18     NULL     NULL     1
17     NULL     NULL     1
16     NULL     NULL     1
15     15       99%      15
14     14       99%      15
13     13       99%      15
12     12       99%      15
11     11       99%      15
10     10       99%      15
```

The result of `cte2` is too large to post here, but I can tell you that the hours where `cte2.hourkey` is `null` do not have a single row within `cte2`. There's nothing after Hr15 that could possibly return a positive number for `count(*)`. But `count(*)` somehow returns 1 for those.

Why is this query returning a `count(*)` of 1 for non-existing hours and how can I remove them?

Comment: Try `count(cte2.hourkey)`.

Comment: It returns `0` which is better, but those rows are still showing in the result. And I have no idea how to remove them.

Comment: Then use an `inner` join if you don't want the null values to appear, or did I get you wrong ?

Comment: The COUNT() aggregate funtion increments by one for enery NON-NULL value. If you use the asterisk with count you are specifically asking for a count of every row. If you specify a column from the left joined table however it will only count rows when that table has has been joined.

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT(*)` will return a count of all rows in a particular group, including the row it's on.  If you want it to count a particular column, you need to specify the column, such as `COUNT(cte2.hourkey)`.  This will count non-null records within the group.

```
SELECT d.hour, hourkey, range, COUNT(cte2.hourkey) AS [count]
FROM dimhour d LEFT JOIN cte2 ON
d.hour = cte2.hourkey
AND range IS NOT NULL
WHERE d.hour <= 23
GROUP BY d.hour, hourkey, range                
ORDER BY d.hour desc
```

If you don't want the rows to show at all, you need an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.hour, hourkey, range, COUNT(cte2.hourkey) AS [count]
FROM dimhour d INNER JOIN cte2 ON
d.hour = cte2.hourkey
AND range IS NOT NULL
WHERE d.hour <= 23
GROUP BY d.hour, hourkey, range                
ORDER BY d.hour desc
```

Comment: `count(*)` is equal to 0, which makes more sense. But they're still being displayed.

Comment: @rbhatup Updated per your comment

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
count(*) as [count]
```

returns the number of rows in the result set.  `LEFT JOIN` is guaranteeing at least one row, even if it doesn't match.

To count the matches, then count one of the columns used for the `JOIN` (or the primary key):

```
count(cte2.hourkey) as [count]
```

Note:  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Using them for columns is likely to cause problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To answer from a different perspective, in a way I think may be easier to understand:

If you take out the `GROUP BY`, you get:

```
hour   hourkey  range
18     NULL     NULL
17     NULL     NULL
16     NULL     NULL
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
15     15       99%
14     14       99%
...
```

If you now group by `hour`, `hourkey`, `range`, how many rows do you see for `18`, `NULL`, `NULL`? I spot one row. It's right there at the top. That's what `COUNT(*)` is returning.

And that's how to approach this too: the count you want, is that a count you can easily obtain from this result set? If not, then look for another approach. In your case, you appear to want to do the grouping on `cte2`. So write that instead!

```
select d.hour, sub.hourkey, sub.range, sub."count"
from dimhour d
left join (
    select cte2.hourkey, cte2.range, count(*) as "count"
    from cte2
    where cte2.range is not null
    group by cte2.hourkey, cte2.range
) as sub
on d.hour = sub.hourkey
where d.hour <= 23
order by d.hour desc
```

One difference is that now instead of `0`, you'll get `NULL`, but you could use `ISNULL(sub."count", 0)` to avoid that if it bothers you.